# How to get total number of likes on page posts

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

Is there a simple way to get the number of likes on posts on a page from the facebook graph API. My current Aproach is to get the feeds of the page, and then for each individual post get the ammount of likes.

So First I itterate all the posts on

```
--This make this a ton of times as I can only retrive 100 at a time
/{page-id}/feed
```

And then using each post ID

```
--Make this request even more times
/{object-id}/likes?summary=true
```

But this is horribly inneficient and takes a lot for each page.
So basically the question is, can I get the info making less requests?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This works for me:

```
/{page-id}/posts?fields=message,likes.limit(1).summary(true)
```